# Recommender using classification

Tags: machine-learning, unbalanced-classes, recommender-system

Hi I'm tasked with building a recommender for predicting item categories to users.

I have data about which items the user has viewed and bought respectively.

I'm interested in turning this into a classification problem. Now, if I turn it into a binary classification problem, where bought/view is `1` and not bought/viewed is `0`. I would first have to impute all the negative interactions. Original data:

```
label, user, item, ..,
1,1,A
1,1,B
1,2,C
```

I would need to impute it like so:

```
label, user, item, ..,
1,1,A
1,1,B
1,2,C
0,1,C
0,2,A
0,2,B
```

As you can imagine this explodes the dataset from sparse to incredible dense and large. Especially since i have thousands of items as well as users.

If I then model the problem as a multi-label classification problem. It would look more like this:

```
label, user, ..,
A B, 1
C, 2,
```

But, this severely limits my ability to attach features about the item like its category.

What I'd like to know is what are my options for managing this problem? I'm wondering if there exists algorithms with implicit negtive samples for binary classification, so I can easier manage a smaller dataset. The above also results in a huge data imbalance.

Comment: Why not directly use recommender system like matrix factorization..?

Comment: see eg https://github.com/lyst/lightfm ..implicit methods...

Comment: I have actually explored using lightFM. I would just like to explore more options

Comment: Since the data is temporally correlated maybe recurrent neural network architectures will suit the problem. You can input all the previous bought items one by one plus the item that you wish to predict, then the network outputs the probability of the user buying that item or even just predict a huge list of probable items.